# Executing code on server only

Tags: reactjs, newrelic, isomorphic-javascript

I have an Isomorphic ReactJS app. I have a small bit of JS that is used for monitoring only (provided by new relic), that I would like to place within a React component (To be precise this is a component that displays an image or if there is no image available, displays a NoImage component, I want to use the monitoring to track when the no image is loaded.), but the catch is I would only like this JS code to run when rendered on the server and not the client.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing server-side rendering you can use `componentWillMount()` as that is called on the server (in addition to client), whereas `componetDidMount()` is only called client side. Something like this should work:

```
componentWillMount() {
  if (typeof process != 'undefined') {
    executeCodeOnServer()
  }
  // or...
  if (typeof document == 'undefined') {
    executeCodeOnServer()
  }
}
```